# How to use useState inside useEffect, accessing the updated useState value on component mount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a code that can or cannot receive querystrings. If it receives all querystrings, I want to execute a function:

```
  // state for query
  const [query, setQuery] = useState({
    periodicity: "",
    stock: "",
    date: moment().subtract(1, "y"),
    investment: ""
  });


  // check if there are query strings
  function useQuery() {
    return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
  }
  let qs = useQuery();
  let queries = {};

  // set query strings received
  useEffect(() => {
    if (qs.has("periodicity")) {
      queries.periodicity = qs.get("periodicity");
    }
    if (qs.has("start_date")) {
      queries.date = moment(qs.get("start_date"));
    }
    if (qs.has("symbol")) {
      queries.stock = { value: qs.get("symbol"), label: qs.get("symbol") };
    }
    if (qs.has("investment")) {
      queries.investment = qs.get("investment");
    }
    setQuery({ ...query, ...queries });
    if (
      query.periodicity !== "" &&
      query.stock !== "" &&
      query.investment !== ""
    ) {
      simulate();
    }
  }, []);
```

The `initial state` is the `query` state. What I'm doing is, on component mount, verify if there are query strings and change the component to match the query strings received.

The problem is, I never enter the last `if (query.periodicity !== "" && query.stock !== "" && query.investment !== "")`. I know it's because `useState` will update the state on the next component mount, and that `useEffect` is only running once, before `useState` updates the state. But how can I fix it without entering in a loop?

I can't put the `query` in the `useEffect` dependency array, because if the user fills all data and the `query` state becomes populated, I don't want to automatically run the `simulate()` function, because the user needs to click on a button. I just want to run it automatically if I received all the query strings needed when entering this page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One way I can think of is by creating a wrapper component which processes the query parameters and pass them as `props` to the current component you have. Then initialize your state using the `prop`.

Comment: I feel that the code except the very last `if` block in `useEffect` body can be moved to the function body.

Comment: Hi @Alireza. If I move it to the function body, it will execute `simulate()` whenever the if returns true. But I want to execute it only when component renders

Comment: @OtavioBonder No this is not what I said. I said leave the *if block* as is but relocate the rest. Makes sense?

Comment: @Alireza this would makes me enter in an infinite loop, because the conditions in each if would always be true in each rerender, and then `setQuery` would always change the state

Comment: I cannot see where you might enter a loop. Even if you set state in `simulate` a loop doesn't occur because `useEffect` runs only once and the component becomes stable in the second render. Anyways, it's hard to investigate the problem without a demo. Can you do one in https://codesandbox.io?

Comment: @Alireza basically this is what I'm trying to achieve: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-field-3luyw I couldn't make the codesandbox work because I had to define routes, but the problem I'm facing is in the code in codesandbox

Comment: Can you check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-morse-pxjrx.

Comment: A little adjustment in the `queries = {}` and it worked like a charm. Post as an answer and I'll mark as the solution verified. Thank you very much! Brilliant ideia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the state in the component function body and check it in the `useEffect` callback:

```
function App(props) {
  const initialState = {
    periodicity: "",
    stock: "",
    date: "2019-01-01",
    investment: ""
  };

  let qs = useQuery();
  let queries = {};

  if (qs.has("periodicity")) {
    queries.periodicity = qs.get("periodicity");
  }
  if (qs.has("start_date")) {
    queries.date = qs.get("start_date");
  }
  if (qs.has("symbol")) {
    queries.stock = { value: qs.get("symbol"), label: qs.get("symbol") };
  }
  if (qs.has("investment")) {
    queries.investment = qs.get("investment");
  }

  const [query, setQuery] = useState(
    receivedQueryString(queries) ? queries : initialState
  );

  /*
  *  Rest of the component implementation
  */

  function receivedQueryString(query) {
    return (
      query.periodicity != "" && query.stock != "" && query.investment != ""
    );
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (receivedQueryString(query)) {
      simulate();
    }
  });

  function simulate() {
    props.history.push(
      `/?periodicity=${query.periodicity}&start_date=${query.date}&symbol=${
        query.stock.value
      }&investment=${query.investment}`
    );
    // calls API
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```